# Cannot update SQL Boolean value

Tags: sql, sqlite, flask

For my toggle of a Boolean value with Flask and SQLite I want to change 1 into 0 and 0 into 1 on table `engineering_project`. The message can be successfully flashed so the if function is working. However, the value of `engg_proj_status` in the table cannot be updated:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT engg_proj_status  FROM engineering_project WHERE engg_proj_id =?",(engg_proj_id,))
status = c.fetchone()[0]
if status == 1:
     c.execute("UPDATE engineering_project SET engg_proj_status = ? WHERE engg_proj_id = ?;",(False,engg_proj_id))
     flash("Status changed from COMPLETED to OPEN")
else:
     c.execute("UPDATE engineering_project SET engg_proj_status = ? WHERE engg_proj_id = ?;",(True,engg_proj_id))
     flash("Status changed from OPEN to COMPLETED")
```

Comment: Add `conn.commit()` to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `conn.commit()`

Thanks to [this comment from forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71212597/cannot-update-sql-boolean-value-with-flask-and-sqlite3/74233795#comment125877727_71212597).